# Continuity Equation for fluid in a curved spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, fluid-dynamics, conservation-laws, differentiation, vector-fields

The current of fluid is the vector $J^{\nu}$. In free-falling laboratory due to Equivalence principle holds the known Continuity Equation $\partial_{\nu}\,J^{\nu}=0$, where the ordinary 4-divergence is used. Latter equation was derived in Minkowski spacetime, thus the Christoffel Symbols are all zero for that equation to hold true. Let us denote in curvature coordinates the covariant divergence as scalar function $K=\nabla_{\nu}\,J^{\nu}$. Then transforming latter expression into laboratory coordinates (where the Christoffel Symbols are zeroes), one gets $K=\partial_{\nu}\,J^{\nu}=0$, where above equations were used. Thus, the answer is $\nabla_{\nu}\,J^{\nu}=0$. The author is Dmitri Martila. Is he correct?

Comment: You say "current" here, do you mean the momentum density, $J^\nu=nu^\nu$?

Comment: I mean the $\rho\,u^{\nu}$, where $\rho$ is density of fluid. Yes.

Comment: I'm using $n$ to be the baryon number density, so that's the same. Next question, have you done any web searches of *relativistic Euler equations*? Because pretty much every document I've seen on the subject would answer this question for oyu.

Comment: Density $ρ$ is not a scalar, so $ ρ u^\mu$ is not a vector.

Comment: How can you speak about yourself in the 3rd person?

Comment: @DanielC I am sorry, I am just humble.

Answer (score 4):

Based on your clarification in comments, it sounds like what you're trying to do is to describe the density of momentum and see how to apply a continuity equation to that. The way we do this in relativity is with the stress-energy tensor, which is a rank-2 tensor, not a vector. The continuity equation is then expressed as $\nabla_\nu T^{\mu\nu}=0$.

If, on the other hand, you want to do this for electric current, you do get a current four-vector, and the continuity equation is the one you wrote.

Comment: If it is possible to write continuity equation for electric current (motion of electrically charged particles) in curved spacetime, then it is possible to write the same equation for current of electrically neutral particles: water, milk, etc.